# Why do these ways of returning arrays differ in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two examples:

```
function myFunction(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
 var newArray = [];

  var tempArray = arr.splice(0,1);
 newArray.push(arr.splice(0,1));
 console.log(newArray);

  return arr;
}

myFunction(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

And this one:

```
function myFunction(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
 var newArray = [];

  var tempArray = arr.splice(0,1);
 newArray.push(tempArray);
 console.log(newArray);

  return arr;
}

myFunction(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

The main difference being the line:

```
 newArray.push(arr.splice(0,1)); // Or newArray.push(tempArray);
```

Why does the first example return Array[1] and the second example return ["a"]?

I was expecting to get ["a"] regardless of which way I went, can someone possibly help me understand what is happening here?

I was just trying to take the first element of the array by splicing (which I believe returns an array of the removed elements) and push this array onto my "newArray" so I can ultimately have an array containing nested arrays holding each character. I.e. [["a"],["b"],["c"]...]

EDIT: Please ignore the "size" parameter.
EDIT2: Sincere apologies. I'm not worried about the return statement. Stupid of me to forgot to mention. I'm looking at my console.log output. When I run the script and look at the console, that's when I'm getting Array[1] or ["a"].

Comment: You're splicing twice in the first example. `splice` is destructive.

Comment: Your functions aren't returning Array[1]. The first one returns ['c', 'd'] the second one returns ['b', 'c', 'd']

Comment: In response to your console log scenario. Here are my console log of the first function `[['b']]` and for the second `[['a']]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most important information you need to have in mind: `splice` changes the original array (read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

So, let's see your first function. This line:

```
var tempArray = arr.splice(0,1);
```

Changes `arr`, as expected. But, when you do this in the next line:

```
newArray.push(arr.splice(0,1));
```

You are changing `arr` again!

Your second function, on the other hand, changes `arr` just once:

```
var tempArray = arr.splice(0,1);
newArray.push(tempArray);
```

In a nutshell: just count how many times you have a `splice` in your first function (2 times, changing the original array twice) and how many times you have a `splice` in your second function (1 time, changing the original array only once).

EDIT: regarding the console.log, `newArray` is an array with an array, and that's why sometimes you see `Array[1]`. Do this:

```
console.log(newArray[0]);
```

And now you'll see `["a"]`, `["b"]` or whatever.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but why do I get Array[1]? What does Array[1] even mean? If I'm splicing twice then why don't I get ["b"]?

Comment: You are not getting `["a"]`. You are getting `["c", "d"]` in the first function and `["b", "c", "d"]` in the second function.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I'm not worried about the actual return for now. I'm just looking at the console.log() output. I'll update my question.